# Ms access only shows one record , when printing form

Tags: ms-access

when i print forms for multiple records, it doesn't print all the record. instead it only shows one record and other blank pages with irregular background colours. is there any help?. i'm really in need.

thank you

Comment: First, it's a REPORT and not a FORM? Confirm the Recordsource manually. Open it and see how many records there are to print. Assume you don't have any VBA code that manipulates the report? Clarify 'other blank pages' and 'irregular background colors'... how many blank pages? Do you use a watermark or image for your pages?

Comment: thank you for responding. Actually i am new to access. My boss handed over this job and ask me learn access. right now i am creating an example  for the firm with just 2 records and all the actual field. i export it from excel.  When try to design the form it went well( with the design). After i finished it,all the record shows properly. But when try to print, it prints blank pages and pages with colour which i used for the header( i didn't use header and footer option on form design).

Comment: And some part of the one form comes in the next page. And the background colour of the second form is entirely different. i dont know what to do.

Comment: and i did it in form not in report(just found out). is there any significant difference?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. i figured it out.it is form, i just had to adjust the page length and width to fit in to an A3 paper. And i accidently press alternate back fill colour to some other colour. thank you very much